# serialize and param return issue with PHP and JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, parameters

I have the following code:

```
    var data_str = $('form').serialize();
    alert(data_str);
    $("#SerializeTXT").text(data_str).show();
    $.ajax( {
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'test.php',
        data: data_str,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#result').html(data);
        }           
   });
```

Here is my test.php and the result:

```
<?php print_r($_POST);?>
```

in the #result i get

```
Array ( [itemIDhidden] => 2640 [SelectQt] => 1 [Bread] => Black Bread_0 [Cheese] => American_0 [Toppings] => Bacon_0 [Description] => TWSTE 3 45 T4 )
```

In the SerializeTXT I get

```
itemIDhidden=2640&SelectQt=1&Bread=Black+Bread_0&Cheese=American_0&Toppings=Sauteed+Mushrooms_0&Toppings=Fried+Onions_0&Toppings=Bacon_0&Description=TWSTE+3+45+T4
```

You can see that the post gets only the last element of the multiple selected element.  In SerializeTXT div i get exactly what is selected from the form.

Any ideas and how can I obtain all those parameters in the php file?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Change your `select` element's name from `Toppings` to `Toppings[]`

```
<select name="Toppings" ...
```

to

```
<select name="Toppings[]" ...
```

Then `$_POST['Toppings']` will be an array.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but those select fields are created by the code and I do not know their names.  Also, It did not work.

Comment: @Obichamte2 If the code generated a multiple select without using `[]` in name, then the code is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var form = $('form');
    var data_str = '';
    form.find('input, select, textarea').each(function()
        {
            data_str += $(this).attr('name')+'='+$(this).val()+'&';
        });
    $.ajax( {
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'test.php',
        data: data_str,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#result').html(data);
        }           
   });
    };
```

test.php
print_r($_POST); returns

Array ( [itemIDhidden] => 2643 [SelectQt] => 1 [Bread] => Multi-Grain Bun_0 [Cheese] => American_0,Swiss_0 [Toppings] => Fried Onions_0,Bacon_0,Raw Onion_0 [Description] => TEST TEST TEST [CancelItemForm] => Cancel [BasketItem] => Confirm ).

This array can be easily manipulated in the PHP file.  I hope this helps to some of the people outside